# Как сделать подобную форму

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть модель Shipment,

```
t.integer  "airline_code"
t.integer  "awb"
```

Нужно сделать подобную форму

```
= form_for shipments_path, method: "GET" do |f|
  = f.label :airline_code
  = f.text_field :airline_code
  = f.label :awb
  = f.text_field :awb
  = f.submit 'Track', name: nil
```

Поскольку airline_code и awb, уникальны только вместе, то есть  awb может быть одинаковый у нескольких грузов, но airline_code разные или наоборот (20-12345678 и 256-12345678 или 20-54678952 и 20-74598324), то если введены корректные данные, у нас в базе найдется только один груз с таким номером.
Вот я хочу, что бы после нажатия Track, меня перекинуло на shipment#show, нужного груза, а если груза с таким номером нету, то выдало бы сообщение что данный код не корректный, помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю насколько нормальное решение, но работает.
Получилось как-то так, поправьте пожалуйста если что-то не так

view

```
= form_tag shipments_tracking_path do
  = text_field :airline_code, params[:airline_code]
  = text_field :awb, params[:awb]
  = submit_tag 'Track', :name => nil
```

controller

```
def tracking
    @shipment = Shipment.find_by(airline_code: params[:airline_code], awb: params[:awb])
    if @shipment.present?
      redirect_to shipment_path(@shipment.id)
    else
      flash[:success] = 'Air waybill not found'
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

route

```
  post 'shipments/tracking'
```